# PhpStorm IDE settings sync - SSH Configurations is not synced, why?

Tags: ide, synchronization, phpstorm, settings, jetbrains-ide

I use setting sync in PhpStorm via JetBrains account, but SSH Configurations is not synced.

Is it a bug/feature or this feature is missing?

Comment: The same on PhpStorm Issue Tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-59369